# Resizing point on zoom out

Tags: openlayers-2

I've added a point on map like this but it is static in size.

How to resize that point on zooming?

Map on zoom out

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Resize](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.resize), as *@Mapperz* mentioned is probably the way to go.

Alternatively, If you have lots of points, rather than looping through all the points resizing them, you could **change the layer's `pointRadius` style**  on map zoom so the change happens to all features in one call. I can't say for sure what is better performance, but I would imagine changing the style would if there are many points.

The styling method has drawbacks such as does not have as many options as the Resize does (scale,origin,ratio), it's only a radius.

**[Here is a DEMO](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/pointZoom.htm)**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Resize Features Programatically using Openlayers v2.12

[image]

```
 map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(point.x, point.y), 5);
        vectorLayer.addFeatures([pointFeature, lineFeature, polygonFeature]);

    }

    var origin = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-111.04, 45.68);
    function resizeFeatures(scale) {
        pointFeature.geometry.resize(scale, origin);
        lineFeature.geometry.resize(scale, origin);
        polygonFeature.geometry.resize(scale, origin);
        vectorLayer.redraw();
    }
```

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/resize-features.html
View>Source

Comment: please notice that the point in blue color is static in size

Comment: you can force the point to not resize too that is the default - read the openlayers documentation on geometry - http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html [resize is an option]

Answer (score 1):

You can a style which calculate point Radius depending on the Map Zoomlevel:

```
        // var map = my OpenLayers.Map object
        var styleSel = new OpenLayers.Style({
            pointRadius: "${radius}",
            graphicName: "circle",
            strokeColor: "#004CFF",
            strokeWidth: 2,
            fillOpacity: 0

        }, {
            context: {
                radius: function (feature) {
                    var pix = map.getZoom() * 10; // ten time the zoo level
                    return pix;
                }
            }
        });
        var styleMapSelect = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        "default": styleSel
        });
        var layer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("myLayer", {styleMap: styleMapSelect});
```