# Resizing point on zoom out using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I need to resize a point on zoom.  When you deep zoom the point get larger and on zoom out the point is smaller.

[Resizing point on zoom out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31943/how-to-resize-a-point-on-zoom-out/83909#83909) seems to have exactly the answer.

@CaptDragon posted an image of exactly what I need and then a demo, HOWEVER the demo is now dead.  I've looked into the API that @Mapperz mentions but for whatever reason cannot get my point to resize larger when zooming in.

Can anyone provide a working example similar to that of @CaptDragon?